# Найти сумму всех отрицательных чисел в списке c помощью цикла while, не рассматривая положительные

Tags: python

```
numbers = [-2, -4, -5, 20, 18]
i = len(numbers) 
total = 0
while i >= 0 and numbers[i] < 0: 
    total += numbers[i]
    i -= 1
    print (total)
```

Выдаёт ошибку в 4 строке list index out of range, но i изначально равен 5, да и второе условие соблюдается. Что не так, подскажите.

Всем спасибо, решил так:

```
numbers = [-2, -4, -5, 20, 18]
i = 0
total = 0
while i < len(numbers) and numbers[i] < 0:
total = total + numbers[i]
i = i + 1
print(total)
```

Comment: только один вопрос - зачем здесь `while`?? Идиоматическим решением будет: `res = sum(filter(lambda x: x<0, numbers))`

Comment: Я учусь, это было домашнее задание. Решить с помощью циклов for и while)

Answer (score -1):

индексы в `python` идут от нуля, следовательно, в вашем массиве максимальным индексом может быть только 4, поэтому у вас происходит выход за границы массива.

```py
numbers = [-2, -4, -5, 20, 18]
numbers = sorted(numbers)
i = 0
total = 0
while numbers[i] < 0: 
    total += numbers[i]
    i += 1
    print(total)
```

либо сделать так:

```py
numbers = [-2, -4, -5, 20, 18]
numbers = sort(numbers)
total = 0

for n in numbers:
    if n < 0:
        total += n
        print(total)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Второй вариант кода какой-то совсем уж неправильный )

Comment: @CrazyElf во втором коде я просто поменял ```while``` на ```for```, и после замены обнаружилось, что большая часть кода просто не нужна)

Comment: но это не подходит по условию задачи: `Найти сумму всех отрицательных чисел в списке c помощью цикла while`

Comment: @Интик теперь подходит

Comment: @zolars первый вариант выдаёт "name 'sort' is not defined", а если всё же sorted напечатать, то по итогу выходит 0, что неправильно.

Comment: @Артур попробуйте сейчас

Comment: @zolars ответ: -5
-9
-11

Comment: @Артур это что неправильно? ну уберите принт из цикла и поставьте после него?

Comment: @zolars нее, всё правильно, просто я без сортировки сделал.

Answer (score -1):

```
numbers = [-2, -4, -5, 20, 18]
total = 0
i = len(numbers) - 1
while i >= 0:
    if numbers[i] < 0:
        total += numbers[i]
    else:
        break
    i -= 1
print(total)
```

Comment: Много лишнего. И очень часто будет неверный результат

Answer (score -1):

```
numbers = [-2, -4, -5, 20, 18]
numbers.sort()

res = 0
i = 0

while i < len(numbers):
    if numbers[i] < 0:
        res += numbers[i]
    else:
        break
    i += 1
print(res)
#-11
```

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что после первого положительного числа в списке больше не будет отрицательных? Апд. А у вас там сортировка. На это вообще трэш - вместо одного прохода по списку сортировать его.

Comment: @Эникейщик ну уберите сортировку и блок else. и будет просто перебор.

Comment: Не оптимально, но вполне допустимо.  @AnatolyKritskiy, если кто-то указал на существенные недочеты в ответе, то именно автору ответа следует их исправить.